# Rotate with jQuery, remember position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

I'm rotating a div like in the code bellow.
The problem is that I don't know how to make the element continue from the last position when I click it again. How do I do that? (I was able to do it in a way that didn't work in IE)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jYN2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="square">click me</div>
```

CSS:

```
.square {
    background:red;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.square').click(function () {
    rotate($(this), -180, 1000);
});

function rotate(element, degrees, speed) {
    element.animate({
        borderSpacing: degrees
    }, {
        duration: speed,
        step: function (now, fx) {
            $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
            $(this).css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
            $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Just use two different classes and swap toggle them with jQuery.

Comment: do you want left side or right side image rotation?

Comment: How do you mean Paulie_D? I't doesnt matter Illaya

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jQueryRotator](http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js)...

and use the js code...

```
var value = 0
$("#image").rotate({ 
   bind: 
     { 
        click: function(){
            value +=90;
            $(this).rotate({ animateTo:value})
        }
    }    
});
```

and the working fiddle is...
http://jsfiddle.net/se4xc/
Hope this will work you.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to not have to include some external jquery code but oh well... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Illaya, I unclicked your answer because I manage to do it without external jquery code.
I changed the JS to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$('.square').click(function () {
       if ($(this).hasClass('folded')) {
            $(this).removeClass('folded');
            rotate($(this), 0, 700);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('folded');
            rotate($(this), 180, 700);
        }
});

    function rotate(element, degrees, speed) {
        element.animate({
            borderSpacing: degrees
        }, {
            duration: speed,
            step: function (now, fx) {
                $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
                $(this).css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
                $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jYN2/3/)